# DOM Manipulation With `useEffect()` vs. `useLayoutEffect()`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

Inside my app component i have:

```
function App() {
  
  const appRef = useRef();
  
  return (
    <div
      ref={appRef}
      className="app position-relative overflow-hidden"
      dir="rtl"
    >
      <NavBar cssCalsses="py-14 px-20 px-lg-0" />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <HomePage appRef={appRef} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/tariff">
          <TariffPage appRef={appRef} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/blog">
          <MagazinesPage appRef={appRef} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/blog/:blogId">
          <MagazinePage appRef={appRef} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/free-class">
          <FreeClass appRef={appRef} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/room-log">
          <RoomLog appRef={appRef} />
        </Route>
        <Route>
          <NotFound appRef={appRef} />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
      <MainFooter />
    </div>
  );
}
```

and inside each page component i have something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    appRef.current.style.background =
      "background value ...";
  }, [appRef]);
```

Now if i change the `useEffect` to `useLayoutEffect` i get an error of `Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`.

If i use it like below i wont have any error:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
        document.querySelector('.app').style.background =
          "background value ...";
      }, [appRef]);
```

now:

1. why is this happening?
2. which one is better?? manipulating the `dom` with react `ref` and `useEffect`?? or doing it with `querySelector` and `useLayoutEffect`??

Comment: The `ref` is most likely not being set at the moment the `useLayoutEffect` handle is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address your 1st problem, I created a **codesandbox**.

**CODE :-**

```
import { useLayoutEffect, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const appRef = useRef();

  console.log("parent render start");
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log("parent layoutEffect", appRef.current.style);
  }, [appRef]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("parent effect", appRef.current.style);
  }, [appRef]);
  console.log("parent render end");
  return (
    <div ref={appRef} className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Child appRef={appRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Child({ appRef }) {
  console.log("child render start");
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log("child layoutEffect", appRef.current.style);
  }, [appRef]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("child effect", appRef.current.style);
  }, [appRef]);

  console.log("child render end");
  return <></>;
}
```

**OUTPUT :-**

`parent render start`

`parent render end`

`child render start`

`child render end`

`child layoutEffect undefined`

`parent layoutEffect  CSSStyleDeclaration {alignContent: "", alignItems: "", alignSelf: "", alignmentBaseline: "", all: ""…}`

`child effect  CSSStyleDeclaration {alignContent: "", alignItems: "", alignSelf: "", alignmentBaseline: "", all: ""…}`

`parent effect  CSSStyleDeclaration {alignContent: "", alignItems: "", alignSelf: "", alignmentBaseline: "", all: ""…}`

From the above we can see that :-

- **child's `useLayoutEffect` with `appRef`** as dependency runs before the **parent's `useLayoutEffect` with `appRef`**. Before that `appRef` is still `undefined` because **React updates DOM** before a `useLayoutEffect`. So unless the **DOM has been updated**, the `appRef` will not be set to the **DOM element** which is required by the child.
- On the other hand, **child's `useEffect` with `appRef`** runs after **parent's `useLayoutEffect` with `appRef`**. That's why `appRef` has the correct DOM element value.

**[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-breeze-wivjs?file=/src/App.js)**

Here is a good flow diagram to reference this - https://github.com/donavon/hook-flow